# Need help understandig the 'rep()' function

Tags: r, rep

```
rep (2,5)
rep
```

Hello everyone, I am learning 'R' by watching a Udemy tutorial and I've been following along. Recently I learned seq() and rep() function. However, when I try to run the code written above I get an additional output. The code returns `2.2.2.2.2` and `.Primitive("rep")`. I am using Kaggle notebooks. Help me understand how this functions works, what is going wrong here, and what will happen if we provide multiple input as `rep(2,3,4,5)` or `(1,2,3,4,6,8)`.

Comment: You should skim through the "Introduction to R" manual that comes with R, or one of the many textbooks that explain it in more detail.

Comment: this can help you: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, `rep` is a function. It is designed to replicate its first argument a number of times equal to its second argument. Thus `rep(2, 5)` returns a vector of length 5 with each element as 2.

In R, functions are also objects, and when you input a function's name, R will return the something that tries to be useful by showing that the input is a function and providing the expected arguments. The `.Primitive("rep")` part tells you that `rep` is a primitive function, part of the base R code.

```
rep
function (x, ...)  .Primitive("rep")
```

In this case, `rep` requires at least one argument `x`, which the object to be replicated. The `...` indicates that it can take a number of other optional arguments. To learn about them, you can access the help file for `rep` with `?rep`.

You can call `rep` with more arguments, but the behavior might not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

By typing `rep` without any details, you are asking R to show you the internal "guts" of what the function does.  You can learn more about it by typing `?rep`.  The manual is probably a lot for a beginner but if you scroll to the bottom you will see some useful examples.

I hope this help:

```
rep ("hi", 5)  # print hi five times

rep(c("hi", "hello"), 3) # print the object holding hi and hello three times

rep(c("hi", "hello"), c(1, 2))  # print hi once and hello two times
```